# How to display frame from another frame in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I always get an access violation.

This is how I display a new frame from an old frame:

```
var
  Frame: TFrame;
begin
  Frame := Tfr_data.Create(form1);
  Frame.Parent := form1.sPanel1;
  Frame.Show;
end;
```

Edit:
I have a form named form1 and two panels inside form (panel1 and panel2). I put the frame inside panel2 and want to put the frame on panel1 from the button inside the frame in panel2. sorry for my bad language.. hope you all understand.

Comment: Show real code, not fake

Comment: Your question is not well asked (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information). As David said, the debugger should show you on which line the access violation occurs. That might give you a big hint, what is wrong.

Comment: its my real code inside button on old frame. got acces violation on this line         Frame.Parent:=form1.sPanel1; sorry for my bad, im new here..

Comment: Are both form1 and form1.sPanel1 valid here?

Answer (score -1):

An access violation occurs when you perform invalid memory access. Often using an uninitialized pointer, a nil pointer, a pointer to freed memory, and so on.

The possible sources of access violation there are:

1. `Tfr_data.Create` raises an access violation.
2. `Form1` is `nil` or some invalid value.
3. `sPanel1` is invalid.

Identification of the precise cause of the problem requires the rest of the code. You have it, we don't. Furthermore, running under the debugger will likely identify the precise memory access that is invalid.

Your next step, therefore, is to do some debugging. Take this as your opportunity to learn the noble art of debugging. That is, set yourself the higher goal of learning to debug, and the solution to your problem will be found as a happy side effect of that learning.

Comment: still have access violation. if i place code in form (any form) code work fine. but got access violation if code in frame.    all component valid

Comment: As I said, it's over to you now, and your debugging skills.